# Logstash Reading Same Data (Duplicates)

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, logstash

I'm using logstash input jdbc plugin to read one database and send the data to elasticsearch.
My Logstash.conf file looks like this:

```
input {
jdbc {
    jdbc_driver_library => "${LOGSTASH_JDBC_DRIVER_JAR_LOCATION}"
    jdbc_driver_class => "${LOGSTASH_JDBC_DRIVER}"
    jdbc_connection_string => "${LOGSTASH_JDBC_URL}"
    jdbc_user => "${LOGSTASH_JDBC_USERNAME}"
    jdbc_password => "${LOGSTASH_JDBC_PASSWORD}"
    schedule => "* * * * *"
    statement => "select * from testtable"
    use_column_value => true
    tracking_column => "time"
}
}

filter {
  mutate {
    add_field => { "message" => "%{time}" }
          convert => [ "time", "string" ]
  }
  date {
      timezone => "Etc/GMT+3"
      match => ["time" , "ISO8601", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"]
      target => "@timestamp"
      remove_field => [ "time", "timestamp" ]
  }
  fingerprint {
    source => ["testid", "programid", "unitid"]
    target => "[@metadata][fingerprint]"
    method => "MD5"
    key => "${LOGSTASH_JDBC_PASSWORD}"
  }
  ruby {
    code => "event.set('[@metadata][tsprefix]', event.get('@timestamp').to_i.to_s(16))"
  }
}

output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["${LOGSTASH_ELASTICSEARCH_HOST}"]
        user => "${ELASTIC_USER}"
        password => "${ELASTIC_PASSWORD}"
        index => "test"
        document_id => "%{[@metadata][tsprefix]}%{[@metadata][fingerprint]}"
    }
    stdout { codec => json_lines }
}
```

I tried using this .conf without these lines:

```
    use_column_value => true
    tracking_column => "time"
```

Also tried using:

```
    clean_run => true
```

But Logstash keeps reading same data over and over again.
Can you help me understand why Logstash keeps reading?
Logstash (8.3.1)
Database (PostgreSQL 14.5)
JDBC (42.4.1)

Answer (score 0):

statement query in your jdbc input configuration `"select * from testtable"` will read all the contents from DB table on each run. Input configuration should be as below to avoid reading same data repeatedly.

```
jdbc {
    jdbc_driver_library => "${LOGSTASH_JDBC_DRIVER_JAR_LOCATION}"
    jdbc_driver_class => "${LOGSTASH_JDBC_DRIVER}"
    jdbc_connection_string => "${LOGSTASH_JDBC_URL}"
    jdbc_user => "${LOGSTASH_JDBC_USERNAME}"
    jdbc_password => "${LOGSTASH_JDBC_PASSWORD}"
    schedule => "* * * * *"
    statement => "select * from testtable where time > :sql_lat_value"
    use_column_value => true
    tracking_column => "time"
    record_last_run => true
    last_run_metadata_path => <valid file path>
}
```